# ScrollView doesn't scroll with a ConstraintLayout within

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, android-layout

I tried to add in my xml layout file a ScrollView but id doesn't work. First I erased the scroll of the RecycleView below. I tried to change ScrollView in NestedScrollView but I have the same issue, I tried all.. this is the XML file: **CODE UPDATED**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".RecipesFragment"
android:background="@color/white">

<androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/recipesContainer"
        android:visibility="invisible">

<com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/fab"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="16dp"
            android:src="@drawable/add"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            android:contentDescription="@string/add_button"
            android:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimaryDark"/>

       <!--Two TextView here-->


        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recipesList"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20sp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/nameText"
            android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"/>

        <!--One TextView here-->

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>


<com.google.android.material.progressindicator.CircularProgressIndicator
    android:id="@+id/progressBarRecipesContainer"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    android:indeterminate="true"
    app:indicatorColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"/>

   </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

What's wrong? Maybe the FrameLayout as parent?

Comment: Why do you have a `FrameLayout` as the parent?

Comment: I thought that for the fragments the setted layout was FrameLayout.. But now I changed with ConstraintLayout

Comment: I updated the code

Comment: FrameLayout is just when you want to allocate some kind of a block on a screen and you are right to use it for fragments. Even I thought it was causing the issue but seems like that's not only the case

Comment: Yeah, it isn't the problem